# How to load Angular library which contains lazy modules dynamic?

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading

I am trying to do like this:

Usually we add a lazy module like this in routing.ts,

{ path: ‘taskCenter’, loadChildren: './taskCenter/taskCerter.module#TaskCenterModule' },

now,I want to loadChildren Dynamic from an package which is produced by rollup or ng-packagr !! Dynamic!

eg:after Aot build,when url is 'localhost:4200/#/taskCenter',it will dynamic load taskCenter.umd.js and it's child modules from assets folder

First,how can we package all lazy modules in library?
Then,how to load this module dynamic?

```js
// First, in Library ,how to package all code including TestChildrenModule
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: ModuleaComponent
      },
      { path: 'aa', loadChildren: './test-children/test-children.module#TestChildrenModule' }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ModuleaComponent],
  exports: [ModuleaComponent]
})
export class ModuleaModule { }
```

this link maybe can help:https://github.com/lmeijdam/angular-umd-dynamic-example

Answer (score 0):

> Lazy loading should happen at an application and not a library level

From this disscussion: [article link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373)